# overriding updateGradInput method in torch is not working for my self defined module

Tags: lua, machine-learning, deep-learning, torch

I implemented a module called sharedModule for my own use. And I have overriden the updateGradInput method below:

```
    function SharedModule:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
    test_grad = {}

    print("call updateGradInput")
    test_input = input
    test_gradOutput = gradOutput
    assert(type(gradOutput) == 'table' and #input == #gradOutput)

    local T = #input
    for t = 1, T do
            self.gradInput[t] = self.clones[t]: updateGradInput(input[t], gradOutput[t])
            test_grad[t] = self.gradInput[t]
    end
    print(#self.gradInput)  -- print normal value 
    --self.gradInput = test_grad  -- 
    return self.gradInput  -- empty, ???
    end
```

However, when i call backward method on my module, the self.gradInput field is not updated, what's the problem, any one can help me out?

Comment: I checked this field but got an empty. However, when i called updateGradInput method directly, it's working all right

Answer (score 1):

backward method will call two methods named updateGradInput and accGradParams, turns out that the error occurs in accGradParams because of typos